# Anyone recommend a replacement for Postmaster addon?

Tags: postmaster, mailing

For v5? I think the addon is not developed anymore and stopped at v2. Basic functions needed are: mailout confirmation on signup/registration specific to different groups.

Anything out there?

Answer (score 0):

I know of a couple of guys who teamed up to make postmaster EE5 compatible. They have it available and plan to release it in the near future. However due to legal stuff it will only be available to people who own a license to postmaster. You can contact me for more info